# curl with nodejs express - POST data

Tags: node.js, curl, express

I'm trying to simulate a POST request to a server app based in Express for nodeJS.  It's running on `localhost:3000` (JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/63SC7/)

I use the following CURL line:

```
 curl -X POST -d "{\"name\": \"Jack\", \"text\": \"HULLO\"}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:3000/api
```

but get the error message:

```
Cannot read property 'text' of undefined
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Note: I can make a successful GET request using this line:

`curl http://localhost:3000/api`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're trying `req.body.text`,

Have you `use`d [`bodyParser`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#bodyParser)?

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());
```

Comment: That worked great thanks!  Do I need to add this line to the server code whenever I want to work with POST data?  Don't suppose you know of a good online resource to learn a bit more about this?

Comment: The `bodyParser` is optional middleware.  By default, Express doesn't parse request bodies.  So yes, you need to `use` the `bodyParser` (once per app), or you can include it in an individual route's middleware chain if you don't want/need to parse request bodies for every request.  To learn more, the Express [guide](http://expressjs.com/guide.html) and [API reference](http://expressjs.com/3x/api.html) are a good place to start.

Answer (score 2):

The answer by josh3736 is outdated. Express no longer ships with the body-parser middleware. To use it you must install it first:

```
npm install --save body-parser
```

Then require and use:

```
let bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser());
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to update Thordarson's answer (which is now deprecated), the currently recommended way is:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/24330353/3810493